# Export csv Contents to a Data Table

Tags: powershell, csv

I was trying to convert the HTML table in my Outlook Mail to extract the particular column based on certain conditions. I was able to achieve the same, by converting the contents to a CSV file and then extract the data from the CSV file and use the Where Clause to extract Select Records from the CSV. The code for the same is given below with the contents in the CSV file.

```
cls

#DEFINE VARIABLES
$sFolder = "TestFolder"
$sSubject = "Approved Users List"
$sCSVFileName = "ApprovedUsersForDeactivation"
$sISODate = get-date -format "ddMMMyyyy_HH_mm_ss"
$sTempFilePath = "C:\Users\NottyHead\AppData\Local\Temp\"
$sDefaultPath = "D:\NottyHead\Convert-OutlookHTMLTabletoCSV\"
$sOutputCSVFileName = $sDefaultPath + $sCSVFileName + "_" + $sISODate + ".csv"
$sFinalTXTFileName = $sDefaultPath + $sCSVFileName + "_" + $sISODate + ".txt"

#DEFINE OBJECTS
$oOutlook=New-Object -ComObject OUTLOOK.APPLICATION
$NameSpace =$oOutlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
$oInbox = $NameSpace.GetDefaultFolder([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders]::olFolderInbox)
$sRequiredFolder = $oInbox.Folders | where-Object {$_.name -eq $sFolder}

$oMail=$sRequiredFolder.items.Restrict('[UnRead] = True')
foreach ($oItem in $oMail)
{
    $sSub = $oItem.Subject
    $sSender = $oItem.SenderName
    if ($sSub -like "*$sSubject*" )
    {
        $oHTML = New-Object -Com "HTMLFile"
        $oHTML.IHTMLDocument2_write($($oItem.HTMLBody))
        $sStrippedData=$oHTML.getElementsByTagName('tr')
        $sStrippedData | % { ( $_.children | ?{ $_.tagName -eq "td" } | % innerText ) -join "," } | Out-File -Encoding ascii $sOutputCSVFileName
    }
}

$ApprovedUserList = import-csv -Path $sOutputCSVFileName
$sApprovedListforSQL = $ApprovedUserList.where({$PSItem.APPROVAL -like 'Y*'}).AD_USER_ID | Sort | Get-Unique 
$sApprovedListforSQL -join "', '" | Foreach-Object { "'$($_)'"} #| Out-File -Encoding ascii $sFinalTXTFileName
```

Contents of the CSV file are as below: -

```
AD_USER_ID,FULL_NAME,EFF_ST_DATE,LAST_LOGIN,ROLE,APPROVAL
jMitterand,Jaques Mitterand,09/09/2016 18:30,12/05/2019 10:15,HoD,Y
dtrump,Donald Trump,07/03/2014 18:30,11/26/2019 03:50,President,Yes
xxiping,Xi Xinping,10/29/2019 18:30,12/02/2019 17:23,Dictator,N
wdalrymple,William Dalrymple,10/29/2019 18:30,10/29/2019 18:30,Historian,Nein
amaino,Antonio Maino,10/29/2019 18:30,12/06/2019 21:25,Politician,Rejected
```

I would like to extract the contents into a DataTable so that I can bypass the use of a CSV file extract records from Unique Records from the DataTable.

Comment: See: [Extend DataTable with easy constructor and AddRow method #11987](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11987)

Comment: And: https://powersnippets.com/convertto-datatable/

Answer (score 0):

This is not using a DataTable, but an alternative to not having to write a CSV file and import it back by making use of `ConvertFrom-Csv` to do it all in memory.

```
$data = foreach ($oItem in $oMail) {
    $sSub = $oItem.Subject
    $sSender = $oItem.SenderName
    if ($sSub -like "*$sSubject*" ) {
        $oHTML = New-Object -Com "HTMLFile"
        $oHTML.IHTMLDocument2_write($($oItem.HTMLBody))
        $sStrippedData = $oHTML.getElementsByTagName('tr')
        $sStrippedData | ForEach-Object { 
            # output a CSV row to be collected in variable $data
            # probably better to match "td" and also "th" tags
            ($_.Children | Where-Object { $_.tagName -match 't[dh]' }).innerText -join "," 
        }
    }
}

$ApprovedUserList = $data | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Of course, if you really insist on getting a DataTable object of the data, you can make use of [iRon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1701026/iron) 's excellent [ConvertTo-DataTable](https://powersnippets.com/convertto-datatable/) function.
In that case convert the $data like this:

```
$dataTable = $data | ConvertFrom-Csv | ConvertTo-DataTable
```

Hope that helps